# Changing numberOfComponentsInPickerView

Tags: iphone, ios, uipickerview

In a UIView I have two UIPicker's with two different datasources. The first datasource is with one component in the pickerview and the second datasource is with two components.

The following code is included in the file:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
    NSLog(@"Refreshing");
    if ([inputSource isEqualToString:@"secondDatasource"]) {
        return 2;
    } else
        return 1;
    }
}
```

The first UIPicker is opening quite well, but after reloadingAllComponents with the second datasource (two components) the problem occurs. The UIView keeps asking for the numberOfComponentsInPickerView and the app is crashing after a few seconds. The log-file is full with "Refreshing".

In iOS 4.3 and iOS 5.0 is everything fine, the problems occurs after installing the iOS 5.1 simulator. The problem do not occur after opening the app on the real iPhone with iOS 5.1.

Comment: what is `inputSource`? And if your pickers have two different datasources, why do you need if statements in your data source methods? It looks like your picker is continually reloading, where do you call the reload from?

Comment: I have two different NSArray's as input source, this is working quite well. The if-statement is checking which pickerview is selected: the pickerview with one component (firstDatasource) of the pickerview with two components (secondDatasource).

Comment: Not enough info to help you. What exact line is it crashing on?

Comment: The app is crashing in this option. When I change the number of components to '1', the app will not crash. The app is crashing when it is returning 2 after it was returning 1 for the first time.

Comment: Why don't you do your if statement on the pickerView instead, if you have them as ivars or properties? That would be less fragile.

Comment: What do you exactly mean jrturton? Do you have al small example?

Comment: A few minutes ago I have installed de iOS 5.0 simulator and the system is working without problems. So, the problem must be in the iOS 5.1 simulator. The system is also working on my iPhone with iOS 5.1. Is there a simulator problem of is there a real problem? Any ideas?

Jrturton, could you possible help me with changing the code to ivars or properties? Thanks in advance!